# Building PostgreSQL with man pages

Tags: postgresql, build, failed-installation

I need to build PostgreSQL from the source code. Everything goes well unless I include man pages.

[The official guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/install-procedure.html) says

> If you want to build everything that can be built, including the
>   documentation (HTML and man pages), and the additional modules
>   (contrib), type instead

```
gmake world
```

As far as I understood, `gmake` is `make`

Here are the last lines of output of `make world`

```
               A new program
      (psql) was provided for interactive
      SQL queries, which used GNU
      Readline.  This largely superseded
      the old monitor program.



               A new front-end library, libpgtcl,
      supported Tcl-based clients.  A sample shell,
      , provided new Tcl commands to
      interface make[3]: *** [HTML.index] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/maxim-dmitriev/PostgreSQL/doc/src/sgml'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/maxim-dmitriev/PostgreSQL/doc/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/maxim-dmitriev/PostgreSQL/doc'
make: *** [world-doc-recurse] Error 2
```

**Update #1**

When I ran `gmake man`, it ended up by throwing `Error 127`.

*The first time.*

```
{ \
      echo "<!ENTITY version \"9.4devel\">"; \
      echo "<!ENTITY majorversion \"9.4\">"; \
    } > version.sgml
'/usr/bin/perl' ./mk_feature_tables.pl YES ../../../src/backend/catalog/sql_feature_packages.txt ../../../src/backend/catalog/sql_features.txt > features-supported.sgml
'/usr/bin/perl' ./mk_feature_tables.pl NO ../../../src/backend/catalog/sql_feature_packages.txt ../../../src/backend/catalog/sql_features.txt > features-unsupported.sgml
'/usr/bin/perl' ./generate-errcodes-table.pl ../../../src/backend/utils/errcodes.txt > errcodes-table.sgml
osx -D. -x lower -i include-xslt-index postgres.sgml >postgres.xmltmp
/bin/sh: 1: osx: not found
```

*The second and third times.*

```
osx -D. -x lower -i include-xslt-index postgres.sgml >postgres.xmltmp
/bin/sh: 1: osx: not found
gmake: *** [postgres.xml] Error 127
```

Comment: What version are you building?  Please show more context that leads to the error.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut, I am building [the documentation for PostgreSQL 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/docguide-build.html).

Comment: You need to install `osx` then.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut, what is `osx`?

Comment: It's a program. It's usually in the `opensp` package or similar.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut, thank you. The error I asked about disappeared. But then I got a lot of "element X undefined" errors. After looking for a solution a bit, I decided not to waste my time on building HTML and man pages; I'll google the issues I'll run into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Building The Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/docguide-build.html) :

> J.3.2. Manpages
>
> We use the DocBook XSL stylesheets to convert DocBook refentry pages
>   to *roff output suitable for man pages. The man pages are also
>   distributed as a tar archive, similar to the HTML version. To create
>   the man pages, use the commands:
>
> cd doc/src/sgml
>   gmake man

This is part of the global `make world` but starting from the subdirectory you may see what specifically fails, looking at of the whole output rather than just the end.

From the piece of output you pasted, it seems it was trying to build the general documentation, not a manpage, and it produces it on screen rather that into a file, which is weird, or it's a very long error message but the interesting part would be above.

In any case, make sure you have a properly working `xsltproc` in your system.

Comment: I am trying to do it now; building both HTML and man pages end up throwing `Error 127`. I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 2):

I also had similar problems building PostgreSQL with docs. You need to make sure you have all the necessary tools installed on your system.

You can find a list of required tools here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/docguide-toolsets.html

Answer (score 0):

You must install next packages in Centos7 for PostgreSQL 9.6 using yum:

```
yum install docbook-dtds docbook-style-dsssl docbook-style-xsl libxslt openjade readline-devel bxslt-devel
```